# Converting Date to proper format when the Value obtained from the Db is in format 2012-07-13 00:00:00.0

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I know there are lot of questions on this topic . But I am not getting a proper solution to my

problem.I am retrieving `Date` from db  , I am getting the Output as

as `2012-07-13 00:00:00.0` .

I am getting  the output in the string format . I want the result of type string in the

format `MM/dd/yyyy`.I am doing the following

```
NSString *dateStr=@"2012-07-13 00:00:00.0";

NSDateFormatter *df=[NSDateFormatter new];

[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSDate *res=[df dateFromString:dateStr];
```

But here I am getting res as `nil` .

Comment: I just googled your question, and see what I got, https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Converting+Date+to+MM%2Fdd%2Fyy+format&aq=f&oq=Converting+Date+to+MM%2Fdd%2Fyy+format&aqs=chrome.0.57.521j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @rptwsthi : please read the entire content of my question just before down voting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this one

```
 NSString *dateStr=@"2012-07-13 00:00:00.0";
 NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"];  

  NSDate *date = [df dateFromString: dateStr]; 

  [df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

  NSString *convertedString = [df stringFromDate:date]; 
  NSLog(@"Your String : %@",convertedString);
```

**Output: 
Your String : 07/13/2012**

Comment: @Raj You know my dear value of Date String is @"2012-07-13 00:00:00.0". So it will give this output.Do you understand?

Comment: But sometimes When the output from the db is 2013-05-16 16:29:52.072  I am again getting nil.

Comment: @Raj see this format [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"]; this will work fine.

Comment: yea that works perfectly fine . I was using "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS , hence it was giving nil , in my case

Comment: please change hh in your answer to HH . I will accept it

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the formatter the whole format of the date, including hours, minutes...

This works:

```
NSString *dateStr=@"2012-07-13 00:00:00.0";

NSDateFormatter *df=[NSDateFormatter new];

[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S"];

NSDate *res=[df dateFromString:dateStr];

[df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

NSString *myString =[df stringFromDate:res];
```

Comment: NoW i Want the Output of type as string in the Format MM/dd/yy. In order to get it Should I write another dateformatter ?

Comment: Just change the format on it, check my code now

Comment: After getting res I am doing                                   NSDateFormatter *df2=[NSDateFormatter new];
[df2 setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy"];
NSString *finalVal=[df2 stringFromDate:res]; .Is this correct ?

Comment: @Dharmbir Choudhary: But sometimes When the output from the db is 2013-05-16 16:29:52.072, I am again gtting nil.

Comment: @Raj in this case you need to change format for this type of string. And first make sure what kind of string string format will you get .

Comment: Yea ..Can u please tell me the format

Comment: Then use: :@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS"

Comment: @Antonio MG: This format yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS  gives nil again

Comment: @Antonio MG:Sorry I meant to say this format yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS gives nil again .

Comment: @Raj [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"]; This will work fine. Try to use this one..

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.s"];
NSDate *aDate=[formatter dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"2012-07-13 00:00:00.0"]];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:aDate]);
```

Comment: if working, then you should checkmark any of these working answers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    NSString *dateStr=@"2012-07-13 00:00:00.0";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[NSDateFormatter new];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S"];
    NSDate *dateObj=[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    NSString *myString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateObj];
    NSLog(@"%@",myString);
```